# CMake does not compile anything

Tags: cmake, structure, project

I don't understand CMake at all, I have this :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(cmake_test)

add_executable(
    cmake_test
    source/main.cpp
)

INSTALL(TARGETS cmake_test DESTINATION ${cmake_test_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
```

Everything configures fine, but nothing is inside bin folder, why doesn't it generate a thing ? Do I have to open every single time VS to build ? What's the sense then ... ?

I want to have this folder structure:

```
[root folder]
    - build
        # CMakeCache and so on

    - include
        - project1
        - project2

    - lib
        - Debug
            project1.lib
            project1.dll
            project2.lib
            project2.dll

        - Release
            project1.lib
            project1.dll
            project2.lib
            project2.dll

    - source
        - project1
        - project2

    - sample
        - bin
            sample1.exe
            sample2.exe

        - src
            - sample1
            - sample2

    CMakeLists.txt
```

Is there any way to generate this simply and easy with CMake ?
I must publish my library on multiple platforms.

Comment: The answer is "yes", the suggestion is to actually read the docs, the vote is to close as "too broad".

Comment: The docs are not explaining why it does not compile. The tutorial is saying that I'm supposed to find my .exe in the folder but it's not there at all

Comment: The basic concept you seem to have misunderstood is that CMake generates e.g. a MSVC solution (in whatever version and for whatever platform you might specify), NMake or Unix makefiles, a KDevelop project or whatever, *which you then in turn use to build the project*. That might not look like much of an improvement if all you are looking at is one specific build environment and a single executable, but once your project grows, CMake starts making more and more sense. [I did build a framework configuration for it](http://jaws.rootdirectory.de) which you might want to look at to get the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the point. CMake is a build file generator. If you don't want to open VS to build, then grab Ninja (or *shudder* GNU make) and use that generator instead.

The point of CMake is that you can write your programs inside your favorite IDE (e.g. Visual Studio), and others who download your project don't need it; they can use any of the other target IDEs/build systems, whether they're on Windows, Linux, or OSX.

Comment: If you want VS to do the build but don't want to open the IDE for building, use the NMake Makefiles generator and call `nmake` on the command line.

Comment: @DevSolar 99% chance that Ninja is way faster, though. VS can be slow for incremental builds; not sure if NMake is the same way.

Comment: I wanted to point out that you can combine VS and CMake for command-line building without any additional requirements. Don't know about relative build speeds on Windows.